# I don't use ads in my flutter app then why this message is showing in my play console?

Tags: android, flutter

I am using Firebase and google analytics though.

> The advertising ID declaration form is now available for you to
> complete.
>
> We'll use this declaration to provide safeguards in Play Console. You
> will not be able to create releases targeting Android 13 until you
> complete the declaration.
>
> Apps using advertising ID that target API level 33 (Android 13) or
> later must declare the normal permission
> com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID in their AndroidManifest.xml.
> This will prevent your advertising identifier from zeroing out. If you
> do not declare the permission in your manifest file, or if you use an
> SDK that omits the permission from their library manifest, this may
> impact your advertising and analytics use cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that Google play has pushed this policy to all developers, and it will be a must for every application in the future.

If you are not using ads, you can choose **NO**.

### Update

If you haven't encountered the popup selection and got this warning while uploading an app to the store, follow these steps in case you are not using AdID:

Go to `App Content` -> `Advertising Id` -> `Does your app use advertising ID?` -> **`NO`** -> **`Save`**

Comment: I have selected NO. But it still says "Your app targets Android 13 (API 33) or above. You must declare the use of advertising ID in Play Console."

Comment: @yongho - I had this same issue. I went back and clicked Yes, and then clicked No, and then clicked Save. That made it go away for me.

Comment: I saw this warning while uploading a new release to the store, But I didn't have any selection option. Where do I select and save NO?

Comment: That didn't work in above case.

Comment: After selecting no if the console says you do have that permission check the merged manifest in my case google play services library was adding this permission

Comment: @Mightian you can add `<uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
        tools:node="remove" />` in manifest file to prevent third-party library injection

Comment: If You have just marked "Does your app use advertising ID?" option to "NO" and then you will have to wait until Google reviews your submitted "No" answer, if this is approved by Google then you will be able to submit / publish your latest app version on google play console.

Answer (score 43):

You need to check if your **final merged manifest**, `AndroidManifest.xml`, includes the permission `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID`or not.

If it does, you need to answer `Yes` and answer the questions that are prompted; if it does not you should answer `No`.

You may not be including this permission explicitly in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it could still be present in your final merged manifest after the build is done, contributed by one of the dependencies you have on your project.

To verify this, you can use the Merged Manifest Viewer on Android Studio and look for `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID`, or check this files on the **build** folder:

```
└── APP MODULE
├── intermediates
│   ├── merged_manifest
│      └── flavourBuild
│          └── out
│              └── AndroidManifest.xml
└── outputs
    └── logs
        └── manifest-merger-prod-release-report.txt
```

Search for `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` inside `manifest-merger-FLAVOUR-BUILD-report.txt` and you will get if it was included, and by what library.

Example

[image: Example - Added by the inclusion of Firebase Config Library a dev of Firebase]

Search for `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` inside `AndroidManifest.xml` and you will get to find if it was included or not.

You can remove the permission by including a removal rule on you AndroidManifest, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105591/1185339), but that can cause problems on the functionality of the dependencies that need it.

Comment: Yes, it found in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `manifest-merger-debug-report` (or release). Thank you for the excellent explanation.

Comment: You can also open the merged manifest directly via file explorer _after_ building your project: `<project>/<module>/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/<build_flavor_name>`.

Comment: Now that I've found those files, and indeed that permission is there, how do I find out which one of my plugins/external packages actually needs this permission? So that I may make an informed choice whether to keep it or not.  (And also to answer the Play Console qns in a meaningful way, as to why this permission is needed...)

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård On the second picture check the ADDED markers. That id is the library that is including it.

Comment: @cristiano2lopes, so it's the library BEFORE the permission that's added the permission, or the library mentioned AFTER the permission...?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård After. You will see uses-permission... and after that ADDED from and the name of the module that added it.

Comment: Not worked this solution for me. Thanks

Comment: If You have just marked "Does your app use advertising ID?" option to "NO" and then you will have to wait until Google reviews your submitted "No" answer, if this is approved by Google then you will be able to submit / publish your latest app version on google play console.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same warning while reviewing my last update. I just went to complete **the advertising ID declaration** (selecting **NO** - since **I don't use any ads in my app**) and the warning just disappeared.

NOTE: I am also using Firebase and its analytics in the app.

Comment: Ok... So it's not Firebase analytics that is the culprit then, it seems! :) I'm still trying to find a way to find this culprit, though...

Comment: Not worked this solution for me. Thanks

Comment: @Kamlesh app info and metadata of our apps may be different and could have affected your side's behavior... I hope you will find the solution ASAP!

Answer (score 2):

## remove from dependence if you not need

flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1+1

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics actually uses that permission.

In order to disable that you need to add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, inside the `application` tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android#disable_advertising_id_collection

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Flutter app when I upgraded to target API level 33. I followed the very helpful instructions from cristiano2lopes to check the build logs which verified that even though I was not intentionally using the advertising ID in my code, the Firebase plugins are including it.

I tried the instructions from Leonardo to disable it. I also found a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2582) about this same issue and followed additional instructions from that to disable it. None of the instructions worked. Google Play Console kept showing the same error even after trying to disable it.

I then updated my Google Play disclosure to say that yes, my app does include the advertising ID. I think updating your disclosure is an easier and better solution if your app depends on Firebase. The disclosure options allow you to select that the advertising ID is used for app functionality or analytics while still stating that your app does not actually include advertising.

Saving this answer here for anyone else who comes across this discussion in the future. If your app depends on Firebase, updating your disclosure may be your best choice.