# Play Store warning: You must complete the advertising ID declaration before you can release an app that targets Android 13 (API 33)

Tags: android, flutter, ads, google-play-console

I am trying to release a Flutter based Android app to the Play Store.

When I review my release in Play Store console, I have the following warning:

> You must complete the advertising ID declaration before you can release an app that targets Android 13 (API 33). We'll use this declaration to provide safeguards in Play Console to accommodate changes to advertising ID in Android 13.
>
> Apps targeting Android 13 or above and using advertising ID must include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the manifest.

I have followed the advice and added the following to my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
</manifest>
```

When I 'flutter clean', create and upload a new bundle, I'm still getting the same warning. Does anyone know how to resolve this warning?

Note: I have incorporated Google Ads in my app using the google_mobile_ads plugin.

Luke

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I don't use ads in my flutter app then why this message is showing in my play console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73132752/i-dont-use-ads-in-my-flutter-app-then-why-this-message-is-showing-in-my-play-co)

Comment: No that doesn't help me because I am using Ads and the answers from that link is for those not using Ads. That link may help @theCaptainXgod. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There are 2 steps that you have to follow to solve this problem.

1. add `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
2. Go to your Google Play Console select the app which you are trying to upload then on the left side go to `Policy and programs -> App content` then select `Actioned` tab, scroll down and find `Advertising ID form` fill this form by clicking on `Manage` button on right side.

So you have already done step 1. Now complete step 2 and upload your app again.

Comment: Hey, can you help me too? I didnt even have ads but they ask for declaration & even though i saved it using NO, my app is not published

Comment: @theCaptainXgod kindly post it as s separate question with details.

Comment: If your app does not use "Advertising ID" then skip step 1 and jump to step 2... Select "No" on the provided form.

Comment: The link for "App content" is now under **Policy and programs** all the way down in the menu. Look for a shield icon with the letter 'i' next to it. After clicking "App content", there are many "To do" items. Scroll down to **Advertising ID** and click Start.

Comment: I am not using any advertisement in my app. I have already select "No" radio option and still getting same message "Your app targets Android 13 (API 33) or above. You must declare the use of advertising ID in Play Console". Not working this solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: If You have just marked "Does your app use advertising ID?" option to "NO" and then you will have to wait until Google reviews your submitted "No" answer, if this is approved by Google then you will be able to submit / publish your latest app version on google play console.

Answer (score 95):

**--- UPDATE September 26th, 2023 ---**

1. Go to your `Google Play Console`, select the app, then on the left choose `Policy and Programs` -> `App content`
   [image: Play console Menu 1]
2. Open tab `Actioned` 
    [image]
3. Scroll down to `Advertising ID` [image]
4. Choose `Manage`, then

- `No` incase you do not use Advertising ID
- Or `Yes` if you (or apps you use) do, like `Google Analytics` or `Firebase Analyicis`  
  [image: screenshot of Google Play Consoles Advertising ID Form]

5. **Only if you answered with `Yes`** above, add the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
   ```

Comment: Just to be clear. I'm updating my app after two years. I have received this warning for the first time. I always show Ads through com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads, but this concept of "Advertising Id" is new to me so I guess I'm not using it. Should I answer "No" or "Yes" to this question?

Comment: @PabloAlfonso I think you are only using an Advertising ID in case you are using the [Advertising ID API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient). --- Fore more info on Advertising ID, see the [Advertising ID Help Page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en-GB)

Comment: This solved the issue for my Xamarin.Android app

Comment: Important detail for me was: Google Analytics and Firebase Analytics use Advertising ID to say who is who. So even thou I do not have ads, I had to check I use it: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039?hl=en

Comment: Must be old - because this area doesn't exist any more.

Comment: I am not using any advertisement in my app. I have already select "No" radio option and still getting same message "Your app targets Android 13 (API 33) or above. You must declare the use of advertising ID in Play Console". Not working this solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: If You have just marked "Does your app use advertising ID?" option to "NO" and then you will have to wait until Google reviews your submitted "No" answer, if this is approved by Google then you will be able to submit / publish your latest app version on google play console.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **Firebase for Analytics or Crashlytics**, we need to declare the use of ads as it it written in this link in the last paragraph https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039?hl=en that the `Android the SDK collects the Advertising ID.`

**1.** First, you need to add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` .

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

**2.** Then, choose **Yes** for the section **Does you app use advertising ID** in the `Actioned tab` of `App Content`.

**3.** **If you keep getting the same message even after you submitted the changes for Ads**, you might have missed the **Declaration for Advertising ID** in the **Need Attention tab**  of **App Content**. At the top of the declaration, is it written that `you can't roll out releases with artifacts targeting Android 13 until you have completed this declaration`. **Click on Start Declaration blue button**.

[image]
[image]

**4.** In the declaration, choose **Yes** for `Does your app use advertising ID` and **check the checkbox** for `Analytics`.
[image]

**5.** Lastly, submit the changes in the Changes Overview. Then, you won't get blocked by the same error message when you try to deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

Some Google libraries use AD_ID internally. If you don't use any advertising in your app, you can add this to your manifest & the warning will be gone on your next release.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```