# Error "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" in Google Play console, even though I removed that permission

Tags: android, flutter, continuous-integration, google-play-console, codemagic

In my Flutter project, I have 2 flavors: `free` and `full`, and I use Codemagic for my CI/CD.

Only the free version comes with a Google ad banner. So I added the `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` permission in the manifest, then run my build on Codemagic, for the full version only.

Then I went to my Google Play console, and I got the error : `This version includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission, but your statement in the Play Console indicates that your app does not use the advertising ID.`, which is true (again, for the full version only).

So I add 2 new `AndroidManifest.xml` files in my project, one in `free`, one in `full`, and removed the permission from the main `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Here is the content of the manifest in the `android/app/src/free` directory:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mistikee.mistikee.mistikee">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
</manifest>
```

And here is the content of the manifest in the `android/app/src/full` directory:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mistikee.mistikee.mistikee">
</manifest>
```

Then I launched a new build on Codemagic, everything went fine, until I went to the Google Play console, and I still got the same error. I really don't understand why. It looks like there is a cache issue somewhere.

How can I fix that, without going to the console telling that I use the advertising ID (because, again, I don't use it in the full version)?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that some package that you use adds this `AD_ID`, for example some Firebase packages do (if I remember correctly Crashlytics and Analytics for example).

Comment: Check `build/app/intermediates/merged_manifest` and `build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests` folders is your project, and look for `AD_ID` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` files to find out.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73132752/i-dont-use-ads-in-my-flutter-app-then-why-this-message-is-showing-in-my-play-co).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at all of that very soon.

Comment: @PeterKoltai You're right, AD_ID is in both merged manifests

Comment: After some research, it's apparently not a problem.
When you see the error in the Google Play Console, you have to tell that, even though your apps contains ads (or, at least, need the AD_ID permission), it's only because your app needs that to work and not for actual ads. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @matteoh could you perhaps self answer this question with the solution you found to mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

even Google Play shows this message you can go to `App Content` -> `Advertising Id` -> `Does your app use advertising ID?` -> `NO` -> `Save`

and the warning will disappear.