# Flutter integration with Facebook SDK (Failed to setup advertising ID permission in Android)

Tags: flutter, facebook, google-play, google-play-console

I just setup facebook SDK in my Flutter app using the [facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events) plugin, following the official facebook guide for both [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android) and [IOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios). I continued to release the app and I encountered this error in Google Play Console:

[image]

I tried to resolve this by adding the following codes to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

I added: `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>` between the `<manifest> ... </manifest> tag`

And I added `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` inside the `<manifest ...>` tag

(Note that I also tried without the `tools:node"remove"`)

Full `AndroidManifest.xml` code as follows:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.cartier.workshop">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="Driwego" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
                android:value="false" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
                android:value="false" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host="myapps.driwego.com"/>
                <data android:pathPrefix="/redirect"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBNh7_pPu1ni8jKLWK-ecY26v3fCGwcgf8" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
</manifest>
```

Note that the error in Google Play Console only appears when I mark my app is using advertising ID (which I'm unsure of) in the app content declaration:

[image]

I would like to know if I should mark "app is using advertising ID" on or off. If it's on, then how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: This has solved for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75239648/error-com-google-android-gms-permission-ad-id-in-google-play-console-even-tho