# Flutter & Play Console: AD_ID permission is not used, yet Play Console insists that it is

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73132752/i-dont-use-ads-in-my-flutter-app-then-why-this-message-is-showing-in-my-play-co).

I'm attempting to publish my Flutter app on Google Play and I'm getting the following warning:

[image]

I've  filled out the AD_ID declaration form and selected "No". I've also checked my merged manifest and there is **no trace** of the AD_ID permission. The app does **not** use ads, or Firebase Analytics. Even the Play Console doesn't recognize it in the App Bundle Explorer:

[image]

When I do select "Yes" on the AD_ID declaration, I get the following:

[image]

Like I said, the final merged manifest does not contain the AD_ID permission. Hoping someone can provide some insight, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you used firebase in your project.
Could you check this?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure

That page tells you what they use that you need to disclose depending on what Firebase services you are using.

Answer (score -1):

1- Go to your Google Play Console select the app which you are trying to upload then on the left side go to Policy and Programs -> App content

2- open tab Actioned

3- scroll down to Advertising ID

4- Here now you can choose Manage, then choose No incase you do not use Advertising ID Or Yes if you (or apps you use) do, like Google Analytics or Firebase Analyicis

Comment: Did you read the question fully?